# Can't get claims when using WSO2 IS as OpenID provider?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I using Identity Server as openid provider.And I add some claims to request,such as "http://axschema.org/contact/email".Then I successfully log in. However, I get null from the response.Why? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There bug reported [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3008) and [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2737) for this behaviour. And, those were fixed and available from next release version of Identity Server 5.1.0.

WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 Alpha2 Released and can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.1.0-alpha2)